# Java - How do I make a thick square of stars with a 4x4 hollow section in the middle?

Tags: java

I'm struggling to know what to put in the if section

```
  System.out.println("\\n");

  for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++) {      
  
     for(int t = 0; t < 12; t++) {
```

********** if(x >= 4 || t >= 4 || x <= 4 || t <= 4 ) { *****************

```
        System.out.print(" * ");
        }
        else { 
           System.out.print("  ");
           }
     
     }//end inner loop
     
     System.out.println();
     
  }//end outer loop
```

What I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Comment: `x >= 4 || x <= 4` is always true. I think you mean `x < 4 || x >= 8`.

Comment: Your condition is always true. It'd be like saying: "If a number is lower, equal, or higher than 0...". In 99% of cases, this doesn't make sense to be an **if** question. Replace both your `x` and `t` conditions with what @shmosel said, and it should work. (Also, print the star at the end of the `String`, and add another space in your blank text, this will fix formatting)

Answer (score 0):

With this you can set the size and the gap of the inner square.  There's no error checking, so that would be on you.

```
public static void printSquare(int size, int gap, char c) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    
    int start = (int) (size/2 - gap/2);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (j > 0) {
                builder.append(' ');
            } 
            if (i >= start 
             && i < start+gap 
             && j >= start
             && j < start+gap) {
                builder.append(' ');
            } else {
                builder.append(c);
            }
            if (j < size -1) {
                builder.append(' ');
            }
        }
        builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    
    System.out.println(builder);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printSquare(12, 4, '*');
}
```